# Why can't some methods be used by another method?

Tags: ruby

Why can't methods be changed/used by another method? In particular, why doesn't this work?

```
puts 'enter a number: ' 
first=gets.chomp
puts 'enter another number: ' 
last=gets.chomp
total = first.to_i + last.to_i
puts 'total of the two values is ' + total.to_s
```

These two variables are now integers. Why can't they be added? I can do this, for example, which isn't that different when you think about it:

```
total = first.lenght + second.lenght
```

Comment: Did you really not put a newline between the puts and gets or is that a Stack Overflow formatting error?

Comment: @Chuck not a formatting error, look at the edit content.

Comment: Code is valid. What is the problem?

Comment: The code should work fine

Comment: -1 for sloppiness. You edited the content of the question (playing the `first=` and `last=` statements on their own lines), and the question is no longer valid. The code you currently have posted is now correct, and no longer needs fixing, making this a very confusing post.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply.my network little slow so i didn't see properly,in future i will not repeat again.thanks once again to explained me ..!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in your code in last line you are doing `puts 'total of the two values is ' + total`

total is returning `integer`,but you are trying to concat to `string` so,it eill throw error like below.

```
1.9.3p448 :013 > puts 'enter a number: ' 
enter a number: 
=> nil 
1.9.3p448 :014 > first=gets.chomp
3
=> "3" 
1.9.3p448 :015 > puts 'enter another number: ' 
enter another number: 
=> nil 
1.9.3p448 :016 > last=gets.chomp
3
=> "3" 
1.9.3p448 :017 > 
1.9.3p448 :018 >   total = first.to_i + last.to_i
=> 6 
1.9.3p448 :023 >   puts 'total of the two values is ' + total
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
from (irb):23:in `+'
```

so,that only we have to change `integer` to `string` like `total.to_s`
or
`puts "total of the two values is: #{total}"` we have to do like that.

Comment: he(@Ruben Rubovski) is having doubt in that so that only i have explained for that also downvote for me ?